# How to push values to an array of object in node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, foreach, mean-stack

```
"default_tabs" : [ 
    {
        "value" : "Ice"
    }, 
    {
        "value" : "Gold"
    } 
 ]
```

I want to assign this values into another array in such a way that 
it should look like below

```
selected_values :  [{"values" : { "Ice" : "Edit","Gold" : "Edit" },"role" : "Admin"}]
```

for this i prepared the below,

```
 default_tabs.forEach(function(i,v){
       selected_values.push('values':v)
    })
```

I know i am wrong can anyone help me please.Thanks.

Comment: Your format is invalid. I can't tell if you want values as an array or an object array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the array and add the properties to the first item of `result.selected_values`'s property `values`.

```js
var object = { default_tabs: [{ value: "Ice" }, { value: "Gold" }] },
    result = { selected_values: [{ values: {}, role: "Admin" }] };

object.default_tabs.forEach(function (a) {
    result.selected_values[0].values[a.value] = 'Edit';
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Nina ..really impressed with your technique of using arrays,Thanks a lot.If can,please suggest me some best articles for arrays.

Comment: @nlr_p, for a start, you could have a look into the documentation from MDN about [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Ok,Thank you ...:)